# Запрос sql с применением индексов

Tags: sql

Дана таблица подразделений с древовидной связью Id <- Parent_Id.
S

```
ET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [Departs]
(
  [Id]        Int           NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  [Parent_Id] Int               NULL REFERENCES [Departs] ([Id]),
  [Name]      NVarChar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Id])
)
GO

DECLARE
  @WithOutDepart_Id Int = ...
```

-- Выдать все подразделения, кроме подразделения @WithOutDepart_Id и кроме всех его детей и внуков

```
...
SELECT D.*
FROM [Departs] D
...
```

Дан параметр – идентификатор некоторого подразделения. Надо выдать все подразделения, исключив из выборки указанное в параметре, а также исключив всех его детей и внуков.

Может стоит добавить индексы?

Comment: Строите обычный рекурсивный CTE на получение дерева. В него дополнительно вводите условие неравенства заданному подразделению. Какие проблемы-то? PS. Индексы не влияют на решение задачи. Вообще никак.

Answer (score 0):

Может вам просто сделать выборку всех id у кого родитель не тот которого стоит исключить.
Если у вас у родителя только один уровень потомков, вам подойдёт простой запрос.

```
   SELECT
      id
    FROM
      [Departs]
    where parent_id != @WithOutDepart_Id
      CONNECT BY Prior id = parent_id
      start with id = :id
```